# JSONB ILIKE indexing

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, full-text-search, sql-like

I have a table `people` with `body` column as a `jsonb` type.

```
                                        Table "public.people"
     Column      |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |      Default       | Storage  | Stats target | Description
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id              | uuid                        |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4() | plain    |              |
 body            | jsonb                       |           | not null |                    | extended |              |

Indexes:
    "people_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_name" gin ((body ->> 'name'::text) gin_trgm_ops)
```

My index looks as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON people USING gin ((body ->> 'name') gin_trgm_ops);
```

However, when I do:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM "people" WHERE ((body ->> 'name') ILIKE '%asd%') LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0;
```

I see:

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..33.58 rows=40 width=104) (actual time=100.037..4066.964 rows=11 loops=1)                                                     
   ->  Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..2636.90 rows=3141 width=104) (actual time=99.980..4066.782 rows=11 loops=1) 
         Filter: ((body ->> 'name'::text) ~~* '%asd%'::text)                                                                                     
         Rows Removed by Filter: 78516                                                                                                           
 Planning time: 0.716 ms                                                                                                                         
 Execution time: 4067.038 ms
```

Why is the index not used there?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer? I'm facing the same problem: strings inside JSONB values fail to use the trigram index with ILIKE.

Answer (score 2):

**update**

to avoid confusion with operators mentionned above I wll quote 
http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/oddmuse/index.cgi/Gin

> Gin comes with built-in support for one-dimensional arrays (eg.
>   integer[], text[]), but no support for NULL elements. The following
>   operations are available:
>
> - contains: value_array @> query_array
> - overlap: value_array && query_array
> - contained: value_array <@ query_array

if you want to use advantages of GIN, use `@>`, not `LIKE` operator

Also, please look at [much better Erwins answer on close question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/5315974)

Comment: Besides, take a look on [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799616/7925366) about non-sargable queries.

Comment: The problem with FTS is that I cannot simulate `%query%` there.

Comment: you don't need to simulate it - `ilike '%val%'` will work fine, it just wont use FTS index. I mean you ask *Why is the index not used there?*, the short answer is *because you use `LIKE` operator*

Comment: We are not using arrays but searching within a string.

Comment: I put confusing quote - sorry. GIN itself is a key-pair store, that's why it is so effective for arrays or jsonb

Comment: I'm looking if there's a particular string matching `name` inside `body`, not if there's an exact JSON in this `body`.

Comment: This answer seems both *incoherent* and *irrelevant*. How does that information answer OP's question?

Comment: OP asks - why LIKE doesnt use GIN on jsonb I answer -  because GIN requires different operators - not `LIKE`, but `@>, && or <@`. obviously you can cast jsonb to text and use `LIKE` but then you will need different index - not GIN.